# How can I do a binary encoding of a string in python?

Tags: binary, python-3.x, ascii, md5

I am trying to build an md5 cracker for practice. Before I go any further here is my code:

```
def offline_wordlist_attack(list_path):
      with fileinput.input(files=(list_path)) as wordlist:
          for word in wordlist:
              md5_hash_object = hashlib.md5() # constructing an md5 hash object
              md5_hash_object.update(binascii.a2b_uu(word))
              word_digest = md5_hash_object.digest() # performing the md5 digestion of the word   
              print(word_digest) # Debug
```

My issue is with `md5_hash_object.update(binascii.a2b_uu(word))`. The [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/hashlib.html) Python 3 documentation states that the string passed to `update()` should be in **binary representation**. The documentation uses `m.update(b"Nobody inspects")` as an example. In my code, I can not simply attach `b` in front of the variable `word`. So I tried to use the [binascii](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/binascii.html) library, but that library too, has a note in the documentation stating:

> Note
>
> Encoding and decoding functions do not accept Unicode strings. Only
>   bytestring and bytearray objects can be processed.

Could somebody help me out with this? It is getting the better of me.

Comment: note: `fileinput.input()` might be too slow in your case. You could use `md5(word).digest()` without explicit `update()`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to pass in a `bytes` object, rather than a `str`. The typical way to go from `str` (a unicode string in Python 3) to `bytes` is to use the `.encode()` method on the string and specify the encoding you wish to use.

```
my_bytes = my_string.encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 6):

Just call `fileinput.input(...,mode='rb')` to open files in binary mode. Such files produce binary strings instead of Unicode strings as files opened in text mode do.

It allows you to skip an unnecessary (implicit) decoding of bytes read from disk followed by immediate encoding them back to bytes using `.encode()` before passing them to `md5()`.

Comment: This would be another solution. In the more general case, though, it has the downside of not ensuring what encoding you're working with (since it depends on the input file encoding).